# 3 phase computer chip

Tags: ac, integrated-circuit, oscillator, three-phase

I have just had a conversation with a friend who studied quantum computing. Sadly I have forgotten most of the conversation as it was far beyond my knowledge threshold.

Essentially he was saying was that current tradition computer chips are getting smaller and faster but soon we will hit the limit because as the chips shrink we have to pass less current through them. Here, there will be a trade off of chip performance against size.

So as these don't already exist, there must be a good reason why microprocessors can't be build that run on 3 phase AC rather than traditional single phase. Is this because as I understand it, microprocessors have oscillators inside them to generate their clock cycles, these oscillators wouldn't be changing state, but always be fixed, because of the constant flow of electrons? Without the peaks and troughs of single phase, I would assume an oscillator can not oscillate, is that correct?

My knowledge if electronics is pitiful at best, so there is likely some fundamental reason why this isn't mainstream because in my head, this would allow for potentially three times the computing power compared to a traditional microchip.

Thank you.

Answer (score 12):

Most chips don't run on AC, rather they use a DC power source. Computers have built-in AC to DC converters which can take the AC power from the wall and change it to the required DC power the computer needs. It's also entirely possible to run a computer using other power sources like batteries, solar cells, etc.

The oscillators inside of computers are designed to take a DC power source preferably with as little ripple as possible and change this to the high frequency clock used by the chip. If you're interested, do a search for "Pierce Oscillator" and "Phase-locked loop".

If you multiply the frequency of most 1-phase AC power lines by 3 you get a frequency of `~150-180 Hz`, a far cry from the GHz range modern CPU's run at.

Consider this, though:

There are people who routinely overclock their CPU's to extreme limits (in excess of 5GHz). This means it's possible for someone to take the same CPU and theoretically pump a much higher clock through them. There are also oscillators available which can generate oscillations in the terahertz range. Why aren't these used in your computer? Because most chips will not function correctly at these high speeds under "normal" conditions. Case and point? These extremely overclocked CPU's use liquid nitrogen or other specialized cooling systems, and even then they can't be overclocked too much higher to the 10's of GHz range.

Lastly, CPU frequency isn't the only factor in overall computing power. In the early 2000's Intel was selling Pentium 4 chips which achieved `~3.8 GHz` CPU clocks.

My laptop also has an Intel chip, an i5-m430. Even though this runs off of a `2.3 GHz` CPU clock, I would say my laptop has much more computing power than the Pentium 4 computers.

**Response to Rocketmagnet's comment:**

So what would a 3-phase oscillator computer look like? Well, first you'd have to figure out how to hook up the oscillator to the CPU. I would guess you can hook up several single-phase chips between two wires of the oscillator, looking something like this (from Wikipedia):

[image: wikipedia]

In essence you have a triple-core chip which all have out of phase clocks. However, I fail to see how this is beneficial over a triple-core chip all sourced off of the same clock. If anything I would think synchronized clocks would be a beneficial feature when it comes time for inter-core communication.

Comment: But what if the oscillators could produce a 3-phase output? I wonder if that could give some advantage to the logic.

Comment: It's entirely possible (even likely) that the processor's clock generator creates multiple phases (3 is unlikely, but 4 or 8 might be done) and different regions or sub-circuits of the processor core are clocked from different phases. This allows the designer to make up for clock tree skew by clocking off different phases.

Comment: @ThePhoton - That's exactly what I meant!

Comment: Ahh, I see. Makes more sense now.

Answer (score 6):

Microchips universally run off DC. The source of that DC can be anything: single-phase, three-phase, battery, fuel cell, whatever, so long as the DC getting to the chip is within its spec.

Answer (score 5):

The frequency of the mains electricity is far removed from the microprocessors oscillator frequency. A rough outline of what happens is:

Lets assume the mains is single phase, 115V AC 60Hz. The peak voltage is calculated by 115V * 1.414 = ~163V, so this means it varies between +163V and -163V 60 times a second.

Since most digital electronics runs at a *DC* voltage of <12V, (common voltages are 5V, 3.3V, 2V, 1.5V, 1.2V, etc) this is no use as it is. So this is fed into the power supply, where it is [transformed](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Transformer) down to the lower voltages, [rectified](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rectifier) and [smoothed](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Reservoir_capacitor) to produce the desired DC voltages.

So that's the power supply, now how does the microprocessor run on DC?

You are correct in that it uses an [oscillator](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Electronic_oscillator), but oscillators don't need a varying supply voltage to work - the function of an oscillator is to generate a varying waveform at the desired frequency.
The oscillator (example below - input 3.3VDC, output 125MHz square wave) will usually be based around a quartz crystal and produce a frequency of up to 100MHz or so (above this is possible with SAW and other technologies)

[image: CMOS oscillator]

This is still to low for a microprocessor that operated at GHz frequencies, so this signal is fed into a [Phase Locked Loop](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Phase-locked_loop) (PLL) which is usually onboard the chip to multiply the frequency up to the operating frequency.

So hopefully you can see the original 60Hz AC has nothing to do with the microprocessor - the microprocessor will work as long as it gets it's rated DC voltage, which will be something like one or more of those listed above. This could come from a battery (laptop, phone, etc) solar panel or any other power source - if the power source does not output the correct voltage the power supply transforms it to the correct voltage (e.g. 115VAC -> 3.3VDC)

Answer (score 4):

As others note, the power supply and the computer operatyion are essentially unrelated.

One improvement that sound similar to what you mention, but really isn't, is to use 3 states per bit rather than 2 as in almost all computers made.

The ideal number of levels in a data "bit" is "e" - the natural logarithm base. As e is mnon integer you won't see e level computers. But, as 3 is closer to e than 2 is a  computer with 3 level  memories has an edge in some situations.

BUT as the difficulty in  implementing 3 levels is far higher than two levels (on/off, high low) you are vanishingly unlikely to see any 3 level memory state computers. Some were built in Russia many decades ago and they worked as intended, but practical issues has consigned toem to the "interesting:" shelf of computer history - so far anyway.